# break routes out of Node/Express server, but router is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to break the routes out of my Node server because it's getting a little cluttered. I followed a pattern I saw in a tutorial server and made a file routes/routes.js which looks like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router()
// routes in here
module.exports = router
```

I added this line to my server

```
app.use(require('./routes/routes'))
```

but my server won't start and gives the error

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next)) Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

I checked the express docs (version 3.16.3), but I couldn't figure out why router is undefined and can't call 'get'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally have a routes config and I just require that.

```
// config/routes.js

module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/', get.stuff);
    app.post('/api/:id', create.stuff);

}
```

Now in our server, we just require the `routes.js` file, and send `app` to it

```
// server.js

var app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {});

require('./config/routes.js')(app);
```

Comment: That worked. I have kind of a lot of routes, some for html pages and others as API for my applications. Would you recommend other routing files in config like app1routes.js app2routes.js for more modularity?

Comment: and any chance you know what's wrong with my first attempt? I did it in a tutorial, it works over there, and it's really buggin me that i'm missing something.

Comment: The first attempt is that router was never defined. I've never used the app.use(router) code before, so I don't know. What I plan on doing for having a LOT of routes is dynamically creating them by having a routeConfig.json file where it looks like this: [{method: 'get', route: '/', middleware:[authenticate, parseStuff], controller: get.stuff}] and then loop through each route and create the listener.

Comment: Interesting. How do you build the code to execute inside such a dynamically created listener? There is a way to dynamically create that as well?

Comment: That requires a separate question. I'm about to post it and I'll include the link once I answer it.